# Compute the difference percentage between rows using groupby in Python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe df, and I would like to compute the difference percentage between the rows by group of week_number. The result should be the (last price - first price)/ first price in each week_number group.

For example, `week_number 0, (95-100)/100 = 0.05 week_number 1, (80-24)/24 = 2.33 week_number 2, (96-37)/37 = 1.59`  The count of each group of week_number is different.

I have no idea how to compute it using groupby method. Any help or hint would be appreciated.

```
value = [[100,0], [103, 0], [95, 0],
     [24, 1], [79, 1], [34, 1],[80, 1],
     [96, 2], [37, 2]]

df = pd.DataFrame(value, columns=['price','week_number'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pipe` function on the groupby, which allows you to reuse the groupby object:

```
    (df.groupby('week_number')
       .price
       .pipe(lambda df: (df.last() - df.first())/df.first())
       .abs()
     )
 
week_number
0    0.050000
1    2.333333
2    0.614583
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

The code above is about the same as the code below.

```
grouper = df.groupby('week_number')
top = grouper.last()
bottom = grouper.first()

top.sub(bottom).div(bottom).abs()
 
                price
week_number          
0            0.050000
1            2.333333
2            0.614583
```

Again, the whole idea of `pipe` in this case is to reuse the groupby object

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```py
df.groupby('week_number')['price'].apply(lambda week: (week.iloc[-1] - week.iloc[0]) / week.iloc[0])
```

Output:

```
week_number
0   -0.050000
1    2.333333
2   -0.614583
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

To get the absolute value of your percentages change lambda to `lambda week: abs((week.iloc[-1] - week.iloc[0])/week.iloc[0])` or append `.abs()` to the apply function `df.groupby(...)[...].apply(...).abs()`

If you want to see the result as percentages you can use this:

```py
df.groupby('week_number')['price'].apply(lambda week: f'{(week.iloc[-1] - week.iloc[0])/week.iloc[0]:.3%}')
```